# do something in jQuery based of the ending of my URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to do something or call something in jQuery based off the ending of the URL, not full URL name, etc. The ending; example, I would like to `.show()` a div if the url ends in `/#/` But if the URL is `/#/hello` or anything different simply `.hide();

Base URL should not come into play because for some reason it will be changing. *ie.* `www.coolwebsite.com/#/`

Comment: Yes it is very much possible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in pure JavaScript no jQuery needed.

```
if(window.location.href.endsWith('/#/')) {
  $div.show();
} else {
  $div.hide();
}
```

Assuming $div is the jQuery representation of the div to show / hide.

Comment: You said pure JS and added jQuery in it? :o

Comment: The check is pure js, the example contains the hide / show of the div which is jQuery but not part of the check...

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. :) It would be nice to add that clarification in your question itself. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the path using `location` object. Consider your path is:

```
https://example.com/path/?myUrl#hash/value
```

Now with this, you can get:

```
hash: "#hash/value"
host: "example.com"
hostname: "example.com"
href: "https://example.com/path/?myUrl#hash/value"
origin: "https://example.com"
pathname: "/path/"
port: ""
protocol: "https:"
search: "?myUrl"
```

You can use simple `if` or `switch` to process your DOM Contents. One best use case is to show the tabs using the `#hashValue`:

```
https://example.com/#tab-1
```

Having a URL like the above, we can get the `#tab-1` from `location.hash`. And using jQuery:

```
$(function () {
  // Hide all the elements with the class tabs.
  $(".tabs").hide();
  // Show the element with the id tab-1.
  $(location.hash).show();
});
```

Hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
if (hash.search(/#\/$/) >= 0) {
    $("#theDiv").show();
}
else if (hash.search(/#\/hello\/$/) >= 0) {
    $("#theDiv").hide();
}
```